# jQuery append to div on click from the different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a `div` of online users which are dynamically inserted:

```
<div id="users">
  <div class="privateMessage" data="John">John</div>
  <div class="privateMessage" data="Maria">Maria</div>
  <div class="privateMessage" data="Tony">Tony</div>
</div>
```

Then I have a `div` for private messages:

```
<div id="messageBox">
</div>
```

Now, I'm struggling how to dynamically append a `div` inside the `messageBox` when I click on the user.

What I need is this below:

```
<div id="messageBox">
   //when I click on John from users div this below should be appended
   <div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="John"></div>
  //when I click on Maria from users div this below should be appended and John above
  //will be hidden
   <div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="Maria"></div>
  //when I click on Tony from users div this below should be appended and John and Maria
  //will be hidden
   <div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="Tony"></div>
</div>
```

Whatever I tried, the divs inside `messageBox` get appended more than once.

Can someone help me to solve this with jQuery please?

Link: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kj8swfvm/)

Comment: Would be good idea to show your JS or (event better) link a fiddle.

Comment: Seconding request for fiddle. Also providing this one - is this what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/pLe01k57/

Comment: Your solution creates only one div for the clicked user. I need to be able to append and keep all the divs with users in the DOM.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pLe01k57/1/ - like this?

Comment: @bardzusny almost correct, but the div with the user should be appended only once :( so lets say if Maria exists, don't append anymore

Comment: thanks guys, all of your answers work perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/thetimbanks/hfuurcL7/

The `click` event is delegated since the users can be added to the list dynamically. I also search the `messageBox` for an existing `div` for that user in order to not add another one.

Adding code here as to not just link to fiddle:

HTML

```
<div id="users">
  <div class="privateMessage" data-user="John">John</div>
  <div class="privateMessage" data-user="Maria">Maria</div>
  <div class="privateMessage" data-user="Tony">Tony</div>
</div>

<div id="messageBox">
</div>
```

js

```
$("#users").on("click", ".privateMessage", function() {

    var user = $(this),
        private_chat = $("#messageBox .private-chat[data-conversation-between='" + user.data("user") + "']");

    if (private_chat.length == 0) {
        private_chat = $('<div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="' + user.data("user") + '">Chat with ' + user.data("user") + '</div>');
        $("#messageBox").append(private_chat);
    }

    private_chat.show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After short clarification in the comments, I'm posting a working solution:

```
$('.privateMessage').on('click', function (e) {
  $messageBox = $('#messageBox');
  var whoIsIt = $(this).attr('data');

  var isAlreadyThere = $messageBox.find('div[data-conversation-between="' + whoIsIt + '"]').length;

  if (isAlreadyThere == 0) {
    $messageBox.append('<div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="' + whoIsIt + '"></div>');
  }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLe01k57/2/

Basically: check if `#messageBox` already has conversation (`div`) with clicked-on user, and if not - append it there.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$('.privateMessage').on('click', function (e) {
    var whoIsIt = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#messageBox').append('<div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="' + whoIsIt + '"></div>');
    $(this).unbind();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/5cq2sw8m/1/

Basically bardzusny's solution above plus a $(this).unbind().

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `data` attribute in this way.

[Read more about `.data()` attribute](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

HTML:

```
<div id="users">
    <div class="privateMessage" data-selected="" data-who="John">John</div>
    <div class="privateMessage" data-selected="" data-who="Maria">Maria</div>
    <div class="privateMessage" data-selected="" data-who="Tony">Tony</div>
</div>
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```

Script:

```
$("#users").on("click", '.privateMessage', function () {
    if(!$(this).data('selected')){
        $(this).data('selected', 'selected');
        // do not use '.attr()', use natvie jQuery '.data()'
        var $msgTo = $(this).data('who');
        $("#messageBox").append("<div class='private-chat' data-conversation-between=" + $msgTo + ">"+$msgTo+"</div>");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eu3yot6a/)

---

**Alternatively**, you could just use [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event, and reactivate it later for specific button (f.ex. after the person was removed from the chat):

```
function singleClick(el) {
    $(el).one("click", function () {
        var $msgTo = $(this).data('who');
        $("<div class='private-chat' data-conversation-between=" + $msgTo + ">"+$msgTo+"</div>").appendTo("#messageBox");
    });
}

singleClick('.privateMessage');
```

[**DEMO** (with delete example using `.one()`)](http://jsfiddle.net/81e1gnu8/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it does what you are expecting .Can check data-attribute before appending div's.

```js
$('.privateMessage').on('click', function(e) {
  var isPresent = false;
  var whoIsIt = $(this).attr('data');
  $('#messageBox .private-chat').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).attr('data-conversation-between') == whoIsIt) {
      isPresent = true;
    }
  });
  if (!isPresent) {
    $('#messageBox').append('<div class="private-chat" data-conversation-between="' + whoIsIt + '"></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.private-chat {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="users">
  <div class="privateMessage" data="John">John</div>
  <div class="privateMessage" data="Maria">Maria</div>
  <div class="privateMessage" data="Tony">Tony</div>
</div>
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```